# shared data utilizing multiple processor in python

Tags: python, concurrency, shared-memory

I have a cpu intensive code which uses a heavy dictionary as data (around 250M data). I have a multicore processor and want to utilize it so that i can run more than one task at a time. The dictionary is mostly read only and may be updated once a day.
 
How can i write this in python without duplicating the dictionary?
I understand that python threads don't use native threads and will not offer true concurrency. Can i use multiprocessing module without data being serialized between processes?
I come from java world and my requirement would be something like java threads which can share data, run on multiple processors and offers synchronization primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share read-only data among processes simply with a `fork` (on Unix; no easy way on Windows), but that won't catch the "once a day change" (you'd need to put an explicit way in place for each process to update its own copy).  Native Python structures like `dict` are just not designed to live at arbitrary addresses in shared memory (you'd have to code a `dict` variant supporting that in C) so they offer no solace.

You could use Jython (or IronPython) to get a Python implementation with exactly the same multi-threading abilities as Java (or, respectively, C#), including multiple-processor usage by multiple simultaneous threads.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) for the dictionary. Since writes are infrequent there shouldn't be an issue with sharing it.

Comment: from the docs it seems that a value fetch will return a copy of data using pickle? a task for me typically access 1/3 of dict which would mean lots of temp objects in this approach

Comment: Then there's no good solution in CPython for your issue. Only a series of not-quite-awful ones, all involving some sort of database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this in the stdlib:
http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html
There are a bunch of wonderful features that will allow you to share data structures between processes very easily.